# Callback after the end of animation in react-navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Using react-navigation with react-native.
How can jeg run a function at the end of animation?
So I want callback like

```
navigate('RoadObject', () => { at the end of animationto do something... });
```

My tab navigator:

```
const MainNavigator = TabNavigator({
  Map: { 
    screen: MapScreen
  },
  RoadObject: { 
    screen: RoadObjectScreen
  }
},
{
  animationEnabled: true
});
```

Comment: You can try to use [Interaction Manager](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/interactionmanager.html)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [Transitioner | React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/views/transitioner)?

Seems like this might be relevant for your case...

Transitioner is a React component that helps manage transitions for complex animated components. It manages the timing of animations and keeps track of various screens as they enter and leave, but it doesn't know what anything looks like, because rendering is entirely deferred to the developer.
Under the covers, Transitioner is used to implement CardStack, and hence the StackNavigator.
The most useful thing Transitioner does is to take in a prop of the current navigation state. When routes are removed from that navigation state, Transitioner will coordinate the transition away from those routes, keeping them on screen even though they are gone from the navigation state.

## Example

```
class MyNavView extends Component {
  ...
  render() {
    return (
      <Transitioner
        configureTransition={this._configureTransition}
        navigation={this.props.navigation}
        render={this._render}
        onTransitionStart={this.onTransitionStart}
        onTransitionEnd={this.onTransitionEnd}
      />
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had some problem with transictions too. I was entering on a Screen with Camera and it got too slow. So I decided to keep the Camera off before finishing the transition animation and after that I turned it on.

Example:

```
import React, {Component, createRef, RefObject} from 'react';
import {SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity, View} from 'react-native';
import {Camera} from 'expo-camera';
import {CameraType} from 'expo-camera/build/Camera.types';
import {FontAwesome} from '@expo/vector-icons';
import {StackNavigationProp} from "@react-navigation/stack/lib/typescript/src/types";

export interface State {
    type: CameraType,
    hasPermission: boolean | null,
    takenPictures: Array<string>,
    isNavigating: boolean,
}

export interface Props {
    navigation: StackNavigationProp<any>,
}

export class CameraMan extends Component<Props, State> {
    private readonly camera: RefObject<Camera>;

    constructor(props: Props) {
        super(props);
        this.camera = createRef();

        this.state = {
            type: Camera.Constants.Type.back,
            hasPermission: null,
            takenPictures: [],
            isNavigating: true
        }
    }

    async componentDidMount() {
        this.props.navigation.addListener('transitionEnd', e => {
            this.setState({
                isNavigating: false
            });
        });

        let permissionResponse = await Camera.requestPermissionsAsync();

        this.setState({
            hasPermission: permissionResponse.granted
        });
    }

    render() {
        if (this.state.hasPermission == null) {
            return <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
            </SafeAreaView>;
        }

        if (!this.state.hasPermission) {
            return <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
                <Text>Acesso negado!</Text>
            </SafeAreaView>;
        }

        return (
            <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
                {
                    (this.state.isNavigating) ?
                        <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#000'}} />
                    :
                        <Camera style={{flex: 1}}
                                type={this.state.type}
                                ref={this.camera}>
                            <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'transparent', flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                                <TouchableOpacity style={{
                                                      position: 'absolute',
                                                      bottom: 20,
                                                      left: 20,
                                                  }}
                                                  onPress={() => this.switchCameraType()}>
                                    <Text style={{fontSize: 20, marginBottom: 13, color: '#FFF'}}>Trocar</Text>
                                </TouchableOpacity>
                            </View>
                        </Camera>
                }

                <TouchableOpacity style={{
                    justifyContent: 'center',
                    alignItems: 'center',
                    backgroundColor: '#121212',
                    margin: 20,
                    borderRadius: 10,
                    height: 50,
                }} onPress={() => this.takePicture()}>
                    <FontAwesome name="camera" size={23} color="#FFF" />
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </SafeAreaView>
        );
    }

    private async takePicture() {
        const capturedPicture = await this.camera.current?.takePictureAsync();
        console.log(capturedPicture?.uri);
    }

    private switchCameraType() {
        const selectedCameraType = this.state.type == Camera.Constants.Type.back ? Camera.Constants.Type.front : Camera.Constants.Type.back;
        this.setState({type: selectedCameraType});
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
    }
});
```

Based on this: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-events/